# Pyside global menu not works

Tags: pyside

Why not work global menu in PySide? I'm developing a Qt app in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and the global menu doesn't work with PySide binding. With PyQt4 it works fine with no problem. 
Is it a bug?

With Pyside

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(400, 300)
        self.centralWidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralWidget"))
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.menuBar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menuBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 400, 25))
        self.menuBar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menuBar"))
        self.menuMenu = QtGui.QMenu(self.menuBar)
        self.menuMenu.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menuMenu"))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menuBar)
        self.mainToolBar = QtGui.QToolBar(MainWindow)
        self.mainToolBar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("mainToolBar"))
        MainWindow.addToolBar(QtCore.Qt.TopToolBarArea, self.mainToolBar)
        self.statusBar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusBar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusBar"))
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusBar)
        self.actionAsd = QtGui.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionAsd.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("actionAsd"))
        self.actionAsd2 = QtGui.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionAsd2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("actionAsd2"))
        self.menuMenu.addAction(self.actionAsd)
        self.menuMenu.addAction(self.actionAsd2)
        self.menuBar.addAction(self.menuMenu.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None))
        self.menuMenu.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Menu", None))
        self.actionAsd.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Asd", None))
        self.actionAsd2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Asd2", None))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

With PyQt4

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(400, 300)
        self.centralWidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralWidget"))
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.menuBar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menuBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 400, 25))
        self.menuBar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menuBar"))
        self.menuMenu = QtGui.QMenu(self.menuBar)
        self.menuMenu.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menuMenu"))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menuBar)
        self.mainToolBar = QtGui.QToolBar(MainWindow)
        self.mainToolBar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("mainToolBar"))
        MainWindow.addToolBar(QtCore.Qt.TopToolBarArea, self.mainToolBar)
        self.statusBar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusBar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusBar"))
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusBar)
        self.actionAsd = QtGui.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionAsd.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("actionAsd"))
        self.actionAsd2 = QtGui.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionAsd2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("actionAsd2"))
        self.menuMenu.addAction(self.actionAsd)
        self.menuMenu.addAction(self.actionAsd2)
        self.menuBar.addAction(self.menuMenu.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None))
        self.menuMenu.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Menu", None))
        self.actionAsd.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Asd", None))
        self.actionAsd2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Asd2", None))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please show an example of your problem and be sure to include code.

Comment: I am sorry. You're right.